# clone() in jquery problem with IE and chrome

Tags: jquery, html, dom-manipulation

i am trying to clone a particular div and do some manipulation to clear the content and return.

```
var tmp = $('<div>').append($('#masterdiv').clone()).remove().html();
```

It works fine in firefox. but in IE and chrome, this removed the entire div instead of cloning.

Whats the workaround for this?

Edit:

The main aim is to copy the entire master div and clear the contents inside the child divs and update it in the database using json. The actual master and child divs(which i take it as place holders for my content) will be rendered from database.

It should not clear the existing content unless the admin approves the layout.

So i tried to clone the div and manipulate, then the problem cames with the IE and chrome..

Comment: Why do you call remove()? The node shouldn't be attached to the DOM

Comment: As far as I can see you could just do `var tmp = $('#masterdiv').html();`

Comment: How can i get the html inside the masterdiv(child divs with cleared content). But it should not affect the page appearance unless i update it and visit that page again. For ex.: I may have some content inside the child divs to show in the page. I like to change the background color of some child divs and update in database and goes for admin approval in my application. Once the admin approves, the page takes the latest changes.

Comment: what was your solution ? I didn't really understand your comment on the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that catches my eye is that you are not passing a valid markup string to your $() function.  For example, `$('<div>')` should become `$('<div />')`

From the [jquery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery):

> All HTML must be well-formed,
> otherwise it may not work correctly
> across all browsers. This includes the
> case where $("<span>") may not work
> but $("<span/>") will (note the
> XML-style closing slash).

There may be something else going on here for you, but this is the first thing you should correct.

Good luck!

Comment: i did as you said(well formed tags), but still the problem exists only in IE and chrome, it works well in firefox.

Comment: The real problem is with the self closed html tag in the page. This has been solved when i corrected it.

Comment: means removed the closing `</html>` tag ?

Comment: @coding_idiot, i had the self closed tag(like <div/>, which is incorrect ofcourse) in the master div, which was causing the issue in IE and chrome. May be in these 6 years of enhancement to the jquery and browsers, this can be handled better